# custom filter in ng-repeat with a function

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting from the json second this way 4:9 (if seconds < 10 ofcourse)
instead of getting 4:09 i've tried to make a custom filter

```
     <a ng-repeat="tracks in recentTracks" | filter:secondsCheck>

         <p>{{tracks.Song}}</p>
         <p>{{tracks.Artist}}</p>
         <p>{{tracks.Album}}</p>
         <p>{{tracks.Length.Minutes + ":" + tracks.Length.Seconds}} </p>
      </a>
```

here is the filter

```
app.filter('secondsCheck', function () {
return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (items[i] < 10) {
            console.log("filter");
            filtered.push(0 + item);
        }
    } return filtered;
};
});
```

but it doesn't even reach the filter function.

Comment: Syntax error? `ng-repeat="tracks in recentTracks" | filter:secondsCheck` should be `ng-repeat="tracks in recentTracks | filter:secondsCheck"`

Comment: What is the value for 'recentTracks'

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom filter, specify the filter's name in the filter expression, not `filter:filterName`.

Also, you're closing the `ng-repeat` attribute too soon.

Fixed:

```
<a ng-repeat="tracks in recentTracks | secondsCheck">
    <p>{{tracks.Song}}</p>
    <p>{{tracks.Artist}}</p>
    <p>{{tracks.Album}}</p>
    <p>{{tracks.Length.Minutes + ":" + tracks.Length.Seconds}} </p>
</a>
```

It looks like there's an issue in the filter's implementation, too. You have `items[i] < 10`, but the values in `items` are not numbers, so this will always be `false`. Hopefully you can sort that out once you get to the point where it's executing the filter.